# Object is not generic (google-maps-react)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, google-maps-react

Just added `google-maps-react` along with `@types/googlemaps` to my project. Now when I attempt to bundle the project I get the below error.

```
../../node_modules/google-maps-react/index.d.ts:29:14 - error TS2315: Type 'Object' is not generic.

29 type Style = Object<string, string | number | boolean>
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What exactly is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add types for `google-maps-react`

`npm install @types/google-maps-react`

Answer (score 0):

In `tsconfig.json` > `"compilerOptions"`, set `"skipLibCheck": true`. It worked in my project in the same situation.

Answer found here: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/12609#issuecomment-895052721.

Why it makes sense:

> Using `"skipLibCheck": true` is the solution, not a workaround. [...]
> In general, a sane approach for an application is to trust its dependencies to be properly typed. So it is not necessary for an application to type check its dependencies. This is also the reason why the default for `skipLibCheck` is `true`.

https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/12497#issuecomment-893339885